# Broken DateListPlot in Mathematica 11.2

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

Fresh kernel, *Mathematica* 11.2, MacOS. Ticks are not shown when using `DateListPlot`.

"`Dynamic Updating Enabled`" option does not seem to affect this.

No obvious way to fix it.

Any ideas?

```
DateListPlot[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11}, {2008, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine on Windows 8.1 64 bit Mathematica 11.2.0.0.

Comment: Maybe because there is a suggestion bar?  Try turning it off?

Comment: This displays properly with Mma v11.2 on my Mac (macOS Sierra v10.12.6) with or without the Suggestions Bar.

Comment: Even tho there is one report that this works on the Mac even if the suggestions bar is enabled, please do try turning it off, as it is more often a nuisance. Otherwise, this doesn't seem reproducible.

Comment: thanks. Turning off the suggestion bar does not fix the issue on my end. I am also running OS X sierra 10.12.6

Comment: I was able to fix this. Just reinstalling didn't fix it. But deleting Mathematica, erasing all the associated directories (detailed here http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12473), and reinstalling it again worked.